# Dompdf set_opacity 'Multiply' only working on first and last page

Tags: dompdf

I'm adding a watermark text to the PDF output with Dompdf. It's working perfectly, the text is showing on every page, but I can't get the opacity to work on every page. For example, with an 8 page PDF tt's showing the correct 0.1 opacity on page one and page eight but on all others in-between it's showing full 1.0 opacity. Here's the full code

```
    // send PDF to the browser
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $options = $dompdf->getOptions();
    $options->setDefaultMediaType('print');
    $options->setIsPhpEnabled(true);
    $options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);
    $options->setIsHtml5ParserEnabled(true);
    $dompdf->setOptions($options);
    $dompdf->loadHtml($pdf);
    $dompdf->setPaper('letter', 'portrait');
    $dompdf->render();

    // add watermark
    if ($watermark)
    {
        $canvas = $dompdf->getCanvas();
        $height = $canvas->get_height();
        $width = $canvas->get_width();
        $canvas->set_opacity(0.1, 'Multiply');
        $canvas->page_text($width/5, $height/2, $watermark, $font = null, $size = 70, $color = array(0,0,0), $wordSpace = 2, $charSpace = 2, $angle = -30);
    }

    return $dompdf->stream(Str::slug($name, '-').'-'.Carbon::now()->format('Ymd-His').'.pdf');
```

Any ideas what could be causing the problem?
Thank you for your ideas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I found a solution so I'll share it with you:

Replaces

`$canvas->set_opacity(.2, 'Multiply');`

by that:

`$canvas->page_script('$pdf->set_opacity(.2, "Multiply");');`

Comment: Crayzo you're a genius! I'd totally given up on this but I changed it now to what you suggested and it works perfectly. Thank you!!! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
//Opacity Will work only on first and last pages because dompdf understand that all PDF is in only single page so $canvas->set_opacity(.2, 'Multiply'); replace with $canvas->page_script('$pdf->set_opacity(.1, "Multiply");');

<?php
    $dompdf = PDF::loadView('pdfViewBlade', compact('data'));
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    $dompdf->render();
    // Instantiate canvas instance
    $canvas = $dompdf->getDomPDF()
        ->getCanvas();
    $canvas->page_script('$pdf->set_opacity(.1, "Multiply");');
    $text = 'Dummy Text'; // Specify watermark text
    $height = $canvas->get_height();
    $width = $canvas->get_width();
    $canvas->page_text($width / 10, $height / 2, $text, null, 240, array(
        0,
        0,
        0
    ) , 2, 2, -27);
    return $dompdf->download('Review_rating.pdf');
    ?>
```